# Too Many Redirects occurs when logging into salesforce sandbox

Tags: browser, salesforce

I am facing this issue whenever I try login to salesforce sandbox via Web.
The authentication seems to be happening correctly, but the constant redirects failed to show me the home page.

Any one facing same issue?
I tried clearing cookie, but doesn't work.
I also tried uninstalling the browser and then install it, also issues remain standstill.
Also tried on other machine in the network, still facing the same issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the solution to above problem.
It seem that post login instruction requires the response in expected timeframe and my network was delaying the response to my machine.
To resolve this, machine should have unrestricted to salesforce and its underlying domain. Also check for the response time for the network.

Comment: can you expand on your resolution? Were these OS, browser or network changes?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue, but found two articles which might be cause of this issue:

[Salesforce critical updates which blocks cross site cookies for not setting same site cookies as secure](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_general_chrome_samesite.htm)

[Google chrome update](https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie)

Both of these together are causing this , so cookies code need to be updated accordingly.

Comment: Those links are of salesforce recent release which mentions the cause . And another link is of google chrome release which is also causing the issue. And # i tried to use as it might work as search keyword.